How to extract dynamically generated links from a website using Python?
I am writing a code where I need to get all the links/URLs from a specific website but, It seems like the links are dynamically generated and might be populated using JavaScript or some other dynamic content-loading mechanism after the initial HTML is fetched.
Initially, I used the following code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.example.com/'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

However, this approach didn't work because the links were not directly written in the HTML. Instead, they are generated later with JavaScript code. How can I extract these dynamically generated links?
A simple hint would be greatly appreciated.

Selenium (https://www.selenium.dev/)?

You're right that the HTML doesn't contain the links so you need an approach that lets the javascript run before scraping the page. I like selenium webdriver and chromedriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.example.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Open an automated browser
driver.get(url)             # Navigate to target page

soup = BeautifulSoup(       # Parse content _after_ any dynamic javascript stuff
    DRIVER.page_source,
    'html.parser'
)

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))


Thanks, it worked! I tried using Selenium WebDriver to scrape content from websites (250+), but it's quite slow. Is there another method I can use?

You can use multi processing so you can run multiple web scrapes at once and just divide the number of links by the amount of processes you want running. e.g 250/5 = 50 pages for each one. You will find a lot of programs that need multiple things happening at the same time use this method.
